# ExceptionType: "System.FormatException" Message: "30/6/2019 is not a valid value for DateTime."

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have two Ajax requests. The first one gets a date from the datepicker and checks with a database date. This is working fine.

The second request gets the date from a datepicker and retrieves the first date of the month and last date of the month. This results in an error.

Here is the WebMethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDateFromDB(DateTime compareDate)
{            
  string selectedDate = compareDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");                           
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

  // testing purpose
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Holiday where Date='" + selectedDate + "'", conn);           
  SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);       
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  sqlDa.Fill(dt);

  if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    return "NG";
  else
    return "OK";
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetFirstDateAndLastDate(DateTime firstDayDate, DateTime lastDayDate, string ddlName)
{
  string firstDay = firstDayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
  string lastDay = lastDayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);

  // testing purpose
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT sum([NumberOfHours]) FROM [LoginDB1].[dbo].[tbOT] where [Date] between Date =  + '" + firstDay + "' And Date =  + '" + lastDay + "' AND name =  + '" + ddlName + "'", conn);
  SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  sqlDa.Fill(dt);     

  return "NA";            
}
```

Script is right below :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $(this).change();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SupervisorOTRequest.aspx/GetDateFromDB",
        data: '{ "compareDate" : "' + dateText + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.d == "OK") {
            alert("Today is Public Holiday!!!");
            $("[id$=txtOTRate]").val(1);
          } else if (response.d == "NG") {
            var date1 = $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('getDate');
            var day = date1.getDay();
            if (day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5 || day == 6) {
              $("[id$=txtOTRate]").val(1.5);
            } else {
              $("[id$=txtOTRate]").val(2);
            }
          }
        }
      });

      var selectedDate = $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker('getDate');
      //  var selectedDate = gg.getDate();
      //var selectedDate = $("[id$=datepicker]").val();
      var firstDay = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), 1);
      var lastDay = new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);

      var firstDayWithSlashes = (firstDay.getDate()) + '/' + (firstDay.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + firstDay.getFullYear();
      var lastDayWithSlashes = (lastDay.getDate()) + '/' + (lastDay.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + lastDay.getFullYear();

      var data = {};
      data.fristDayDate = firstDayWithSlashes;
      data.lastDayDate = lastDayWithSlashes;
      data.ddlName = $("[id$=ddlName] option:selected").text();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SupervisorOTRequest.aspx/GetFirstDateAndLastDate",
        // data: '{ "fristDayDate" : "' + firstDayWithSlashes + '" + "lastDayDate" : "' + lastDayWithSlashes + '"}',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.d == "NA") {
            $("[id$=txtRemainHour]").val();
          }
        }
      });
    },
  }).on("change", function() {});

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

When Inspect the page under Network > Headers > Request Payload, it come out correctly (below) :

{fristDayDate: "1/6/2019", lastDayDate: "30/6/2019", ddlName: "Masrudin Bin A B Rahman"}
ddlName: "Masrudin Bin A B Rahman"
fristDayDate: "1/6/2019"
lastDayDate: "30/6/2019"

However under the preview, the error messages appear like this :

> {Message: "30/6/2019 is not a valid value for DateTime.",…}
>   ExceptionType: "System.FormatException"
>   Message: "30/6/2019 is not a valid value for DateTime."
>   StackTrace: "
>   at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)

Under the response, the errors message appear like this :

> {"Message":"30/6/2019 is not a valid value for DateTime.","StackTrace":"
>   at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)
>   at

Comment: Is your database online?

Comment: Please check [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post to provide just necessary information. Note that showing SQL injection vulnerability examples in the code never improved reception of a question on SO.

Comment: @Licentia what difference "is database online" makes when error is at parameter parsing time (as part of default ASP.Net model biding)?

Comment: The issue with your question is simply that its overcomplicated. You have this string "30/06/2019", show us just the code that is doing the conversion and is failing.. hope that helps

Comment: `"1/6/2019"` needs a `d/M/yyyy` format string or leading zeros for month and day to match your format

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov,  because apparently his database is online but he is running the app on his local machine and it seems to me  the server dateformat does not match the local date format therefore he needs to pass the correct cultureInfo

Comment: @Licentia but you know that call stack would be very different in case error is actually related to DB code... as well as values - which are produced by `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` generating two digit for day -  "dd - The day of the month, from 01 through 31."

Comment: `SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Holiday where Date='" + selectedDate + "'", conn);` Please **do not** do that. Use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Karrieop,

try this

```
DateTime firstDay= DateTime.ParseExact(firstDayDate, "yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```